# Переворот экрана

Tags: python

Решил сделать шуточную программу, встал вопрос, как реализовать переворот экрана на `n` градусов (не изображения а именно самого экрана)

Comment: А экран имеет контроллер поворота? :)

Answer (score 5):

Изменить ориентацию можно через `WinAPI`. Но на `n` градусов повернуть экран не получится. Windows поддерживает всего 4 ориентации:

- Стандартная
- 90°
- 180°
- 270°

***Пример инвертирования экрана:***

```py
import win32api  # pip install pywin32
import win32con

# First device
d = win32api.EnumDisplayDevices(None, 0);
dm = win32api.EnumDisplaySettings(d.DeviceName, win32con.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS)

# Invert current orientation
orientation = (dm.DisplayOrientation + 2) % 4

dm.DisplayOrientation = orientation
dm.PelsWidth, dm.PelsHeight = dm.PelsHeight, dm.PelsWidth
dm.Fields = dm.Fields & win32con.DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION

win32api.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(d.DeviceName, dm)
```

Подробнее: [Changing Screen Orientation Programmatically](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms812499(v=msdn.10))

Comment: Wow интересно! ;)